# How to append XML data without overwriting?

Tags: php

I'm in the process of writing an XML file:

```
<?php
$xml2 = "currenttest";

$xml  = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$root = $xml->createElement ('tv');
$xml->appendChild($root); 

$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("\n"));
$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($xml2));
$root->appendChild($xml->createTextNode("\n"));

$xml->save('epg.xml');
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tv>
test
</tv>
```

If i change the text and again runs the code, the old content is deleted.

And I want the old text to stay.

Let's say this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tv>
currenttest...
newtest...
</tv>
```

My previous way was to write the XML with:

```
file_put_contents($file, $xml2, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX, its helped me that the previous text would not be erased

---

I found a solution in another post:

```
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents('epg.xml'));
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('***') as $node)
{
}
```

But how can it fit into my code?

Comment: can you add the loop code

Comment: well show the code not the file on server it is php you know

Comment: @M0ns1f This is the code above, I have no other code. I just want to know how to append XML data without overwriting the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing particular to do, just to reload your xml string and to append a new text node to your root element:

```
// your previous code (I only changed the variable names and added a default encoding)

$text = "currenttest";

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");

$root = $dom->createElement('tv');
$dom->appendChild($root); 

$root->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("\n"));
$root->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($text));
$root->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("\n"));

$xml = $dom->saveXML();

// let's add a new element

$newtext = 'newtext';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$root = $dom->documentElement; // conveniant way to target the root element
// but you can also write:
//$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tv')->item(0);

$root->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($newtext));

$newxml = $dom->saveXML();

echo $newxml;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/RjNrg)

---

About `$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents('epg.xml'));`, note that you don't need to use `file_get_contents` since `DOMDocument` has already two methods:

- `DOMDocument::loadXML` that loads the xml content from a string.
- `DOMDocument::load` that loads the xml content directly **from a file**.

---

In addition to `DOMNode::appendChild` that adds a node to an element after all the children nodes of this element, you have also `DOMNode::insertBefore` to add a node to an element before the child node of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed the code on top, 'cause i was overwriting my data, but when I coded in my application, it didn't worked cause I was trying to add the new node data in the loaded xml, you have to create a root to add data inside.

```
  $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    //an tag root must be first thing to add
    $root = $xml->createElement('root');
    $xml->appendChild($root);
```

Then, just add the data when you need

```
   $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
   $xml->load($sFilepath);
   $root = $xml->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);
```

your structure must looks like this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<root>
</root>
```

The answer on top is totally correct. This answer is only to help if somebody is having trouble to understand.